# Mesmo controlador para diferentes views

Tags: angularjs

Ao definir as rotas, tenho o seguinte código:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'login' : { templateUrl: 'view/login.html', controller: 'authentication' },
                'navbar-top' : { templateUrl: 'view/navbar-top.html', controller: 'authentication' },                    
                'recover' : { templateUrl: 'view/recover.html', controller: 'authentication' },
                'register' : { templateUrl: 'view/register.html', controller: 'authentication' }
            }
        })
...
```

Tenho diferentes views com o mesmo controlador.
Na view 'navbar-top.html' tenho os botões "login" e "Registrar".
Ao clicar em "login" a view "login" deveria ser alterada, porém nada acontece porque as variáveis não são alteradas.
Pelo que percebi, apesar de ter o mesmo controlador, o angular criar uma nova instância para cada view.

Como reaproveitar e mesmo controlador para diferentes views?

Answer (score 1):

A maneira correta de compartilhar valores entre escopos diferentes é utilizando um serviço (ou, alternativamente, um *factory*). Exemplo a seguir:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
 
app.service('compartilhamentoService', function() {
    this.valor = 0;
});
 
app.controller('primeiroController', function($scope, compartilhamentoService) {
 $scope.svc = compartilhamentoService;
});

app.controller('segundoController', function($scope, compartilhamentoService) {
 $scope.svc = compartilhamentoService;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="primeiroController">
        Primeiro controle:
        <input type="text" ng-model="svc.valor">
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="segundoController">
        Segundo controle:
        <input type="text" ng-model="svc.valor">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível diretamente. Mas pode-se utilizar um `service` e preparar o `$scope` para torná-lo acessível e transparente.

A idéia, em linhas gerais, é a seguinte:

Cada view sua deve estar associada a um `controller` diferente ou não. Supomos que seja o mesmo, e vamos chamá-lo de `DummyController`. Sua única função, será preparar o ambiente para que o "controller" (na verdade o `service`) seja acessível e compartilhado pelas views.

Feito isso, implemente seu `controller` como um `service` em Javascript, com tudo que tem direito, inclusive DI.

Agora, basta seu `DummyController` preparar o ambiente para acessar os métodos da classe.

Vamos adicionar código:

**RealOne**

```
angular.module("MyModule", []).factory("RealOne", [ "$http", function ($http) {
    var $scope = null;
    return {
        // método para atulizar o $scope quando a view é alterada.
        // deste modo, manipulamos sempre o $scope da view ativa.
        setScope: function ($newScope) {
            $scope = $newScope;
        },
        // implemente aqui o "controller real".
        fazAlgumaCoisa: function () {
            console.log("wooow");
            return "woooow";
        }
    }
}]);
```

**DummyController**

```
angular.module("MyModule", []).controller("DummyController", [ "$scope", "RealOne", function ($scope, RealOne) {
    $scope.ctrlr = RealOne; // faz com que o singleton seja acessível a view.
    RealOne.setScope($scope); // faz com que o scope correto seja acessível no singleton.
}]);
```

**View**

```
<p>{{ ctrlr.fazAlgumaCoisa() }}</p>
```

Agora, basta adicionar o controller a view, e ele estará acessível pela variável de escopo `ctrlr`.

Deste modo, cada vez que o `DummyController` for instanciado, ele irá utilizar o singleton que criamos na sua primeira incialização.

Deste modo, utilizamos as facilidades de gerenciamento de ciclo de vida dos elementos do Angular a nosso benefício, sem grandes gambiarras.