# Passar objeto entre as views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Como poderia fazer para passar um objeto JSON entre as views:

```
    angular.module('app')
    .controller('MeuControle', function($scope) {
      $scope.listaPessoas = [
        {
          nome: "Patrick",
          idade: 19
        },
        {
          nome: "Joao",
          idade: 17
        },
        {
          nome: "Maria",
          idade: 20
        }
      ];

      $scope.clicada = function(pessoa) {
        $scope.pessoaSelecionada = pessoa;
        $location.path("app/pessoaDetalhe");
      };
    })
```

listando pessoas:

```
    <ion-view hide-back-button="true" view-title="Listando Pessoas">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h1>Inicio</h1>
          <button ng-repeat="pessoa in listaPessoas" ng-click="clicada(pessoa)">
            {{pessoa.nome}}
          </button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Porem a variavel $scope.pessoaSelecionada chega na outra view (app/pessoaDetalhe) vazia, ambas usam o mesmo controller:

```
    <ion-view hide-back-button="true" view-title="Detalhes">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h1>Nome {{pessoaSelecionada.nome}} idade {{pessoaSelecionada.idade}} </h1>


      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Se eu deixar fixo $scope.pessoaSelecionada = {nome: "fulano", idade: 20} os valores passam, dinamicamente não.

Comment: Dependendo da sua aplicação você pode tentar isso: `$rootScope.pessoaSelecionada = pessoa;`

Comment: tente inicializar a variável  `$scope.pessoaSelecionada` com null e me diz se funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente separar em dois controllers diferentes já que são views diferentes. 
Por mais que o controller seja o mesmo, se você tem um "ng-controller='MeuControle'" em duas views diferente, o $scope dos dois vão ser diferentes. Então acredito que você não vai conseguir fazer o que esta querendo.

Se você estiver utilizando "ngRoute", pode passar os valores por parâmetros de um controller para o outro utilizando o "$routeParams" (porem não vai conseguir passar o objeto, só valor por valor).

Toda vez que você der um "$location.path", o controller executa novamente, por este motivo acredito não ter como. Quando você passa fixo, você deve estar passando os valores fora da função "$scope.clicada", certo? Por este motivo deve funcionar.

Exemplo:

```
.controller('MeuControle', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  if ($routeParams.nome)
     alert($routeParams.nome);
  ...
  $scope.clicada = function(pessoa) {
    $scope.pessoaSelecionada = pessoa;
    $location.path("app/pessoaDetalhe?nome=" + pessoa.nome + "&idade=" + pessoa.idade);
  };
}
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, fiz dessa forma, ficou até mais elegante!

Comment: Que bom que consegui ajudar. Obrigado pelo feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Não deu para entender muito bem como está a estrutura das suas views, porém, se estiverem em um único arquivo ou se estiverem usando ng-include, você pode sim utilizar um controller só para mais de uma view, tente passar um alias na instanciação do controller, caso contrário, se você usa um ng-controller em cada view, a alternativa sugerida pelo Alexandre é a adequada como pode ser vista neste link: [Uso de controller em diferentes views](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50472/mesmo-controlador-para-diferentes-views)